# R find the index of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of characters and after some lines of code my list has an element with zero characters. How can i extract the index of the element which have zero characters???
Original list

```
 blocks <- list(
                    c("A", "B"),
                    c("C","D", "E", "R", "T"),
                    c("X"),
                    c("N")
    )
```

Transformed list

```
 blocks <- list(
                    character(0),
                    c("C","D", "E", "R", "T"),
                    c("X"),
                    c("N")
    )
```

Comment: Not sure what you wanted. `blocks[[1]]` gets the first `list` element.  If you need a logical index `seq_along(blocks)==1`.
 If you  need to extract first elements  `sapply(blocks, '[',1)`

Comment: Can you show your expected output? The index of the first element is 1 (in R....).

Comment: The first element of every list element? 
lapply(blocks, "[[", 1)

Comment: in my code i have a repeat function which removes every (A.....N) which is negative. So what i want to achieve is to retrieve the index of the first element and in a later part of my code to use this index in order to remove from a matrix the related column and row

Comment: It is not clear from your comment.  Can you update the post with the expected output

Comment: May be `lapply(blocks, function(x) seq_along(x)==1)`

Comment: I would like to know the index blocks[[i]] when it is equal to character(0).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want, but I guess `grep`can do the trick:

- if you want to know in which element of the list is a letter, use `grep('A', block)`
- if you want to know the position of a letter into the whole list, you can try `grep('A', unlist(blocks))`
- if you want something else, well, try it as well !

Answer (score 0):

If we want to get a logical index of elements that have `character(0)`, we can use `lengths` on the second 'blocks'

```
!lengths(blocks)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

`lengths` is a convenient wrapper for `sapply(blocks, length)` and is much faster.

```
lengths(blocks)
#[1] 0 5 1 1
```

returns a `length` of 0 for the first `list` element.  By negating (`!`), the `0` gets coerced to `TRUE` and all others as `FALSE`.